# Reverse calculations using only one number and sum of reminders

Tags: calculus

Let's imagine we have some big number.

```
2320584520
```

I need to divide it to get some small number not greater than some constant f.e. `256` using iteartions. My calculations:

```
2320584520 / 256 = 9064783 (> 256, reminder 72)
9064783 / 256 = 35409 (> 256, reminder 79)
35409 / 256 = 138 (less than 256, stop calculations, reminder 81)
sum of reminders = 232
```

So here we have 138, 72, 79, 81 and 232. And some formula with 256.
We can easily reverse the calculations with the following :

```
(256 * 138) + 81 = 35409
(256 * 35409) + 79 = 9064783
(256 * 9064783) + 72 = 2320584520
```

But for this we need to know the remainder for each iteration.

Is it possible to reverse calculations using only two numbers 138, 232 (sum of reminders, maybe some other number)? These numbers should be not greater than 256 each.
Let's imagine we know number of iterations and initial formula with 256 as constant.

I tried this way, but understand that something is wrong:

```
((138 * 256) + 232) * 256 * 256 = 2330460160 (!= 2320584520)
```

I apologize right away, I’m a complete layman in mathematics, and for me this question is no less complicated than understanding quantum theory.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suggest finding a different set of three numbers adding up to 232, then do the reverse calculations with that set of remainders. If you get a different number, then you will know that just knowing the sum of the remainders is not enough.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for responce but no progress at all. By convention, we do not know the original number. Accordingly, we cannot compare the result and understand that it is different. We only know the result of the first calculation (138), the sum of the remainders (232), and the number of iterations of exponentiation 256. We do not know the remainders for each iteration.

Comment: I also tried to find another approach, such as determining the nearest number to the 4th power (to shorten the original number), and the difference with the original number.
Original: 2320584520
219^4 = |2300257521 - 2320584520| = 20326999
So we have 219. And 20326999 that also should be represented as 1 - 256...
But this is also a dead end for me.

Comment: The point of my comment was, you can make up some remainders that add up to $232$, then do your reversal of calculations to find the big number that would lead to those made-up remainders. If the big number you get from the made-up remainders is different from the one in your original example, then that proves that there is no way to reconstruct the original number if all you know is the sum of the remainders.

Comment: In any event, it's a good idea to make some response, some acknowledgement, to users who are trying to help you on this website